# How to do a comparison between A or B between ten samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, paired-data

I am planning a research which will go as follows,

There will be ten participants and each will perform the same exercise. However they will be wearing the variant A or variant B of the garment we are testing (each participant will do the exercise with both A and B variants donned)

The question is what statistical model can I use to see whether A or B is better in terms of the variables being tested.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's great that you are thinking of this issue before conducting the experiment. 
 Please tell us about the variables being tested: how many and how will they be measured?  Given the values of these variables on any two participants, exactly how will you determine which set is "better"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There are several variables which are not finalized yet. But as an example, peak power output (Newtons) and jump height (meters) are two variables that will be tested. I wish to see the performance of the A and B variants overall after conducting the experiment with all ten participants wearing the variants A and B.

Comment: Thank you: but how should we translate "performance ... overall" into quantitative statements about peak power and jump height? When one individual is better than another on peak power but worse on jump height, exactly how do you determine which one is better "overall"?

Comment: Hey, we are not going to compare between individuals. The comparison is between the variant A and B, which I forgot to mention variant B is the control and variant A will be the experiment garment. So for each participant we will have a baseline performance (when wearing the control B) and increased or decreased performance (when wearing the experiment A). Hope this makes sense. I am new to drafting research methodologies.

Comment: But you *are* comparing properties of individuals, because you will be averaging their performances.  In what sense could garment B perform better than A if on average it helps peak power but hinders jump height?

Comment: ok so for the sake of my understanding, let's say that the study is only on determining peak power output between A and B across ten participants. Can you help point out the issue in my methodology.

Comment: You don't describe your methodology.  For instance, how do you plan to control for the order in which the garments are worn?

Comment: There will be two test dates one week apart. On both days the study environment and participants' lifestyle will be controlled as much as possible (environment temp, sleep, food intake 12h before etc). Participants will be randomly assigned A or B on either day ensuring that every participant will wear each variant once. They will do 3 sets of 5 countermovement jumps per garment. The average peak power output of the 3 sets will be calculated.